# Passing Java ArryList<String> to JNI C function and print the list in C

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, native

I have the following native method in Java :

```
public class ConsoleIO
{

    public native static void printList(List<String> list);

   ......
}
```

and the corresponding C implementation with JNI is the following :

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_ConsoleIO_printList(JNIEnv *env, jclass cls, jobject obj)
{



}
```

Now I need to pass a list of Strings from java to the printList(List list) method and loop through it from the above C implementation and print them in the console from the C function.

I know that there is no C representation of this List type, but I need to know that how I can do access this List of strings in C and print them out in C itself?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Here is a [tutorial](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/javanativeinterface.html)

Comment: @Blake I went through this but there is no any example of accessing a generic type list... Thanks anyway !

Comment: Ah I see your question is specifically about passing the `List` argument from one place to the other. I don't know how to do it with a `List` specifically; it might be easier to proxy it through an array. See [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/types.html) guide.

Comment: It would be far easier to format the desired text output into a string ending in '\0', get the bytes with the native character encoding, pass the byte array to JNI and treat it as a native string. Tip: if your native method has an appropriate public signature, consider Converting it to a Java method that pre- and post-processes for private methods that would be simpler to implement in JNI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for this :

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_ConsoleIO_printList(JNIEnv *env, jclass cls, jobject obj)
{

    jclass listClass = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env,obj);

    jmethodID sizeMethod = (*env)->(env,listClass,"size","()I");
    jmethodID getMethod = (*env)->GetMethodID(env,listClass,"get","(I)Ljava/lang/Object");

    jint size =  (*env)->CallIntMethod(env,sizeMethod);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java has [Type Erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypes.html). So `List<String>` becomes `List` in the compiled code.

So what you are really looking for is to implement the below Java calls using JNI:

```
jint size = list.size();
for (jint i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    jobject elem = list.get(i);
    jstring str = (jstring)elem;
    ... print str ...
}
```

In the above C code, `list.size()` and `list.get()` must be replaced with calls of `GetMethodID`, `CallIntMethod` and `CallObjectMethod`. The string can be retrieved from `str` using `GetStringChars` or `GetStringUTFLength`. And some memory management is needed: `ReleaseXXX`.

Comment: Thanks for this, but i really don't know how to do it since I'm a beginner for JNI